# Using quotes in HAML attribute values

Tags: ruby-on-rails, escaping, haml

I am using HAML in Rails and I need to have an attribute containing quotes.

```
=form_tag({url: "/upload", multipart: true }, {test: "'test'"})
```

This results in

```
<form ... test="&#39;test&#39;">
```

However, I need to have it generated like this:

```
<form ... test="'test'">
```

What can I do

Answer (score 1):

If the **html_safe** method is added to the string it works:

```
=form_tag({url: "/upload", multipart: true }, {test: "'test'".html_safe })
```